# Автообновление курса валют в БД

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Как сделать автообновление курса валют в БД без открытия сайта т.е. каждый день в одно время будет обновление непосредственно в БД.

Comment: 1. создать скрипт обновления 2. повесить этот скрипт на cron

Comment: Добавлю, у ЦБ есть апи курса валют.

Comment: Знаю что есть API, вопрос как обновлять БД без открытия сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и ответил вам [Total Pusher](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/287469/total-pusher) - сделайте скрипт обновления прямо в БД.
Повесьте этот скрипт на CRON (планировщик задач), который будет запускать скрипт раз в сутки.

Цитирую:

```
Знаю что есть API, вопрос как обновлять БД без открытия сайта
```

Вот, почитайте:
https://ru.hostings.info/schools/cron.html

У каждого хостинга свои нюансы работы с CRON. Вот, например, инструкция для Masterhost:
https://masterhost.ru/support/doc/cron/ - посмотрите справку своего хостинга.

А вот простенький калькулятор правильных команд для CRON (возможно пригодится):
https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Думаю оно самое, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов.